Does Dash-to-Panel no longer work on ubuntu 22.04?
I have executed the script given on the official dash-to-panel github page here.
However, the following command in this script:
gnome-extensions enable "dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com";
Generates the following output:
Extension “dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com” does not exist.
And the extension is in fact not installed.
Is this a known issue in ubuntu 22 or 22.04?
EDIT:
trying to instead download it via Extension Manager gives me this popup:

If I press the green button I get:

Alternatively, if I just try to search for it in the app Extension Manager, I don't find it.

An extension could only work provided it is installed. Provided you install it using the Extensions Manager tool, it should work fine. However, before enabling that extension, disable the build-in Ubuntu Dock extension first. Both extensions want to manipulate the same aspects in different ways, and hence are incompatible with each other.
I was able to install the extension using Extension Manager. So in principle, still should work on Ubuntu 22.04.

Did you read the link I posted? I honestly don't understand how you can give this answer if you did. The title in the link I gave literally is dash-to-panel - Installation.

Anyway, trying to open it with Extension Manager I'm hitting a problem which I described in my question.

Please read twice. I did not name the extension. However, I refer to the Ubuntu Dock extension, which you need to disable before enabling the Dash To Panel extension. The link you gave instructed you to execute make install, not the script given below.

I managed to install the extension without any issue from the Extensions Manager tool. It even activates directly, apparently without turning off Ubuntu Dock. I advice to do that yourself in the "Installed" tab.

To find it in Extension Manager, set the sort order to "Downloads". Extension Manager appears to limit the matching items it displays, with no option to scroll down. So were it not for the sort option, and for the fact that this is one of the most downloaded extensions, you would not be able to find it using the tool. This is still early software, after all. However, it will be the easiest way to install the extension. The answer to your question is that it still is supposed to work. It is maintained and supports up to Gnome Shell 46.
